# Building a open source media server

Tags: linux, media, mp4

I'm looking into the possibilities of building an open-source streaming media server on Debian. It will be serving a mix of mp3 and mp4 files, perhaps 10-30 streams at a time, fairly high quality.

What are the possibilities for a Linux streaming media server that is totally open-source?

Answer (score 0):

[`XBMC`](http://xbmc.org/) and [`MythTV`](http://www.mythtv.org/) are two popular media server software distributions that come to my mind. They are also available as individual packages that you should be able to install on any distro.

In addition to media server functionality, `MythTV` provides DVR and TV tuner functionality as well.

Answer (score 0):

I always thought of XBMC and Mythtv as stream consumers, rather than stream providers. Can't speak to XBMC at all. Myth can definitely provide streams and it sets them up pretty much out-of-the-box ready to go. Not sure it can handle 30 concurrent streams. If you want that many, I'm guessing this will go beyond your home network and you want something that can be hardened and exposed to the internet. I'd recommend mediatomb as a streaming server. Maybe also lots of RAM for a filesystem cache and an extra couple of network cards. I think that's where your bottleneck will form.